# Date code on Exide Edge FP-AGM78 Flat Plate AGM Sealed Automotive Battery

Tags: battery, code

I have 2 of these batteries, purchased 3/17 and 6/17 in the US from a third party seller on Amazon. The stickers on the side show the re-charge dates of 3/17 and 6/17 respectively. I am trying to figure the actual manufacturing dates on these.

Under the QR code there are two lines of codes:

First battery:
152930293K & 078770D1A with ACKT26A & 070770D1A heat stamped

Second Battery:
141380327L & 078770D1A with ACER24N heat stamped

These are Group 78 with 770CCA, that is included in the second line.

Anyone know the meaning of these?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!